# opening a txt file in an editor with python

Tags: python, xml, wxpython, window, text-files

I'm newbie with python, I'm writing a program with python to let the user select an XML script and the python program will automatically parse the XML and create a txt file using header info from the  XML and open that txt file in a text editor window.

I've figured out everything but how to get the txt file opened in the text editor

I'm using

```
notes = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos=(10, 85), size=(550, 400), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
```

to create the text editor 
and `f = open('out.txt','w')` to create the txt file itself

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if understand the question entirely, but to open a pre-existing txt file with python using the default app. You could use

```
import webbrowser
file = "TEXT.txt"
webbrowser.open(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the contents of the extracted text to show up in your `wx.TextCtrl`, correct? If so, try this:

```
data = "converted text from xml file"
notes = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos=(10, 85), size=(550, 400), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
notes.AppendText(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the Python XML parsing modules, like xml.dom or download the lxml module. Run the parser and whatever is returned, you can put in your text control:

notes = wx.TextCtrl(parent, value=parsedText)

Or you can append the text as "samplebias" mentioned.